# How do I remove the apostrophe before inserting into MYSQL? (not simply escaping them)

Tags: php, mysql

i have a program that fetches titles of webpages that sometimes have apostrophes.  i don't simply want to comment them out and escape them with \s.  how can i get rid of them all together?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) should work:

```
$string = str_replace("'", "", $string);
```

Comment: $string = str_replace("'", "", $string);

Answer (score 1):

You may use this function to clean up titles from any unwanted characters.

```
function clean_up( $text ) {
    $unwanted = array("'"); // add any unwanted char to this array
    return str_ireplace($unwanted, '', $text);
    }
```

Use it like:

```
$dirty_title = "I don't need apostrophes.";
$clean_title = clean_up($dirty_title);
echo $clean_title; // outputs: I dont need apostrophes.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $string);
```

This method is PHP & MySQL safe and doesn't alter the appearance of the string when it's echoed. Useful when dealing with names like O'Brian.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a string that contains apostrophes, add below line in code that will escape them:

`$data = str_replace("'", "\'", $data);`

Answer (score 0):

if you try to trim before mysql update, or insert into ...

```
$string = str_replace("'", "", $string);
```

is fine but mysql can use another sign instead of trimmed one.

Here what I developed is trimming after echoing mysql value.
Reading from mysql:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT value1 FROM db WHERE id='1'  ");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo str_replace('"', '', $row["value"]);
}
}
```